# How to generate Excel test report from Appium with mocha chai?

Tags: automated-testing, appium, typescript, mocha, chai

I would like to generate a simple test report in Excel.

My automation is using Appium with chai mocha, and successfully reports the results of my 2 test cases to the command line.

How can I send my test results to an Excel file?

Answer (score 2):

By default, as per the [Mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#reporters) on reporters, there is no Excel reporter. There are some CLI reporters (Spec, Dot, etc) and there are HTML and JSON reporters.

A quick Google search shows there is an NPM package called [Mocha-Insights-Reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-insights-reporter) that can generate Excel files.

Since Mocha is open-source and has documentation, your other option is to create your own Excel reporter.